# Flutter TextFormField validation creates memory leak by creating infinite widgets according to Flutter Performance inspector

Tags: flutter, optimization, memory-leaks, flutter-textformfield

Creating a simple Login/Register UI and need to validate Username/password and noticed that on 'Flutter Performance' inspector if I press multiple times on the button which 'validates' the TextFields it creates as many widgets as I press the button. In the end the memory usage is gradually increasing.

I believe I'm missing something some fundamentals here on how to dispose the created widgets after validation.

Could someone educate me on the situation on how to avoid memory leaks on Flutter?

I'm attaching my Flutter Performance screen.

[image: Flutter performance memory leak after validation]

Comment: please add your code